# Keep only numbers with comma separator in numerical lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some values like following:

```
630,465
theGlobe
504,685
OpenDiary
Open
Diary
17,738
JUNE
1998
/////////////////////////
Bolt
bolt3,270,300
Classmates
1,509,260
```

Now i want to remove extra content from numerical lines.
for example I want to remove `bolt` from `bolt3,270,300`

**I tried following regex:**
**Find What:**
**^.*?(\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\b).***
**Replace With:**
**$1**

**but this regex remove** `bolt3` **from** `bolt3,270,300`

**I tried following regex too:**
**Find What:**
**^.*?(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*).***
**Replace With:**
**$1**

**but this regex remove** `8` **from** `1998`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?(?<!\d)(?<!\d,)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?!,?\d).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/POaXHg/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately on the left
- `(?<!\d,)` - no digit and comma allowed immediately on the left
- `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one, two or three digits and the zero or more occurrences of a comma + three digits
- `(?!,?\d)`  - no digit or comma + digit allowed immediately on the right
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.